# Chef doesn't call the second line of the PS script

Tags: powershell, chef-recipe

I'm using Chef Kitchen to do a POC. We have a PowerShell script which goes to a network path, sorts the build based on date [Install shield installer], copies to the VM in a folder.

This script works correctly when I run inside the VM manually using Power Shell. When I run using Chef Kitchen I don't get any error, the recipe is run but only the first line.I can see the folder called Build created in the VM.

I did an experiment and added a second line to create another folder, it worked correctly. So the issue is the logic I used to copy and paste the build doesn't seem to work with Chef.

The first line creates a new folder, the second and third sets the source and destination path. The fourth line copies the build from the network path [Sort by date to get the latest] to the VM. And the last one is to rename.

And also is there an efficient way to copy a file from a network path [Sorting by date] to a VM using Chef?

```bsh
powershell_script 'CopyBuild' do
  code <<-EOH
New-Item -ItemType directory -Path C:\Build
$source = gci \\BuildPath\Build | ? { $_.PSIsContainer } | sort CreationTime -Desc | select -f 1
$destination = "C:\Build"
Copy-Item "\\BuildPath\Build\$source\*" $destination
Get-ChildItem $destination -r -i "*app1*.exe" | Rename-Item -NewName {"Test.exe"}
EOH
end
```

I also tried this, calling the PS script:

```ruby
cookbook_file 'getbuild.ps1' do
  mode '0755'
end
```

Comment: Does appending a semicolon to each PowerShell statement help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a windows remoting problem, your powershell needs the right configuration to be allowed to access network shares.

To verify if this is the case: replace the UNC path and just copy a local directory - if this works you can dig further to setup the requirements for windows remoting, see the following links for further help:

1. [Safely running windows automation operations that fail inside winrm or powershell remoting](http://www.hurryupandwait.io/blog/safely-running-windows-automation-operations-that-typically-fail-over-winrm-or-powershell-remoting) (see chapter No access to network resources)
2. [Knife issue 655](https://github.com/test-kitchen/test-kitchen/issues/655)
3. [enabling and using credssp](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/windowsserver/en-US/ab722e45-8fca-40bc-acfb-499c11569411/enabling-and-using-credssp)

To sum these links up: you can schedule a local task in your PS which does the copy to achieve this, or setup credssp.